# Questions about complex measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The following proposition is from the *Real Analysis* by Folland:

[image]

where the definition of $|\nu|$ is as the following:

[image]

Here are my *questions*:

> - In the proof of 3.13(b), $g|f|=f$ $\mu$-a.e. since
>     $$
>   g|f|\ d\mu=f\ d\mu.
>   $$ Could anyone explain why we have "hence $|\nu|$-a.e."?
> - [Added:] Why "clearly $|f|>0\  |\nu|$-a.e.?

Comment: For Part (b), after showing that $\nu=|\nu|$, we actually have that  $$d\nu=g\ d|\nu|,$$ which implies by definition that $$d|\nu|=|g|\ d|\nu|$$ and thus $|g|=1\ |\nu|$-a.e.

Comment: Where have we shown $| \nu| = \nu$? I think b follows from what you wrote above without this(?) 

$$ \int_E (1 - |g| ) \, d |\nu|  = 0 \text{ for all } E \in \mathcal{M} $$ 
Hence, $|g|=1, \, |\nu|$ a.e. But I don't understand why $|f| > 0 $ $|\nu|$ a.e. either.

Comment: @CWL: I don't remember why I wrote that comment, which seems nonsense to me now... Maybe it is a reply to somebody else's comment which contained some extra assumptions but not deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $d\nu = f\, d\mu$, $d|\nu| = |f|\, d\mu$. So if $E$ is the set of points $x \in X$ such that $g(x)|f(x)| \neq f(x)$, then $\mu(E) = 0$, which implies $|\nu|(E) = \int_E |f|\, d\mu = 0$. Therefore $g|f| = f$ $|\nu|$-a.e..

Comment: May I ask why "clearly $|f|>0$ $|\upsilon|$-a.e."? Thanks!

Comment: @sam2018 if $A = \{x : f(x) = 0\}$ then $|\nu|(A) = \int_A |f|\, d\mu = \int_A 0\, d\mu = 0$. Therefore $|f| > 0$ $|\nu|$-a.e..